# Looping through the Fetch_API seems not to be working for me

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have fetch the data from an API and trying to loop through the json data which I have received from URL, But I ma getting error and it says 'posts.map is not a function. I have looked through internet but could not received the answer I am looking for. Appreciate your help!

here is my reactjs code:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    posts: [],
    error: null,
    users: []
  }

 async componentDidMount(){
    const URL_API = `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/posts.json`;
    const response = await fetch(URL_API);
    const data = await response.json(); //this is asyncronous calls that 
    return us the json data
    this.setState({
      posts: data,
      isLoading: false,
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { posts } = this.state
    console.log('posttt', posts);

    return (
     <React.Fragment>
        <h1>React fetch - Blog</h1>
          <hr />

        <ul id='list'>
         {posts.map(post => (
           <li 
              key={post.id}>
             <span>{post.title}</span>
             <span>{post.content}</span>
           </li>

         ))}
        </ul>

     </React.Fragment>

    );
  }  
}

export default App;
```

[image: ![The error I am getting in the console:]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm84C.png)

Comment: Try `posts.posts`

Comment: `posts` is an object the property on it named `posts` is the array, meaning you want to access `posts.posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the data returned from the API is an object with a `posts` key.
So either set the state with `data.posts` or loop over `posts.posts`.

The first option seems more reasonable in my opinion.

```
this.setState({
      posts: data.posts,
      isLoading: false,
    })
```

Comment: Thanks alots, it was a silly mistake from my side but thanks for your quick response. It works !